# Conjecture about uniquely 3-colorable triangle-free graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Assume graphs are simple and undirected and colorings are proper vertex colorings. Define a chromatic triple as three vertices that have distinct colors in every coloring. The conjecture is:

If a 3 colorable  graph  $G$  has no subgraphs that are uniquely 3 colorable (thus G is also not uniquely colorable and triangle free), then $G$ does not contain any chromatic triple.

I believe that this conjecture  would also  prove that all planar triangle free graphs are 3-colorable, since they can't be uniquely colored and must have a minimum degree of at most 3. I have quite a few generalizations and variations in mind, but first wondered if this is indeed correct and if not, what a counterexample would look like.

Comment: Does "no subgraphs that are uniquely 3 colorable" allow a subgraph to be both "not colorable" and "can be colored by multiple coloring"?

Comment: Forgot to put in that G is assumed to be 3 colorable

Comment: A counterexample is the cycle graph on six vertices, C6, which is 3-colorable, not uniquely 3-colorable, and triangle-free. However, it contains chromatic triples since any proper 3-coloring of C6 must use all three colors on consecutive vertices.

Comment: @rumathe  R-B-R-B-R-Y, would be a proper coloring not using each color on 3  consecutive vertices

Comment: Your conjecture is actually equivalent to Hadwiger's Conjecture, which is still an open problem, but your claim about planar, triangle-free graphs is true and is known as Grötzsch's Theorem

Comment: @rumathe I don't see the equivalence. Then you'd say  also that Hadwiger conjecture implies Grotzsch theorem? Can you give an argument maybe?